# Extracting values from a text file

Tags: excel, vba, file, text, extract

I would like to achieve a data extraction from a text file, using VBA Excel. The text file (output of an engineering software) contains a lot of values.
I can locate the values I'm interested in thanks to keywords that are always located before the values.

Here is a typical example of my text file content :

```
random_text_before_keyword  [keyword1]       0.375    -0.080/   0.020      1.000
random_text_before_keyword  [keyword2]       0.530     0.367/   0.465      1.115
random_text_before_keyword  [keyword3]       0.363     0.200/   0.298      0.938
random_text_before_keyword  [keyword4]      19.225    21.206/   21.179     -71.834
```

Some difficulties :

1. keywords and values are separated with random spaces (and sometimes tabs also)
2. values can be preceded by "-" sign (need to keep)
3. there is sometime a "/" char after values (better not to keep it)
4. values are not integers (decimal numbers)
5. values are not all the same length

My goal would be to extract the four values in few lines ([keyword1] and [keyword3] for example) and to place them in an Excel worksheet:

```
A1; B1; C1; D1
A2; B2; C2; D2
```

For now, I found a topic pretty close to what I may need to do but a little help would be much appreciated.
[using excel vba read and edit text file into excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299041/using-excel-vba-read-and-edit-text-file-into-excel-sheet)

Comment: Read line-by-line, and for each line replace all `vbTab` with a space, replace all \ with `""`, replace all double-spaces single space until all you have is single spaces.  Locate the keyword using `Instr()` then use `Split(restOfTheLine, " ")` to get an array of the values you want.

Comment: You can do Dim newString As String = Replace(stringToRemoveFrom, "/", "") to get rid of /

Comment: Hello Pnuts, it works pretty fine directly with Excel (without VBA). If I do not succeed with a code solution, that is probably what I'll continue to do, but it is very time consuming :/ I didn't know that a text to colum command exists in VBA. I need to experiment ! Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Tim and justkrys. I feel closer to the solution!

Comment: Also, if you don't know, anything you can do manually in Excel, like click on a tab, format cells, etc, you can also record as a macro and Excel will write the code for you to automate it.

Comment: I progressed in the code but feel stuck with the "RestofTheLine" part. I don't know how to code it :/

Answer (score 1):

For testing the function below:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim l As String, arr, gotMatch As Boolean, v

    'you will be reading this from a file....
    l = "random_text_before_keyword  blahblah  " & vbTab & _
          "   0.530     0.367/   0.465      1.115 "

    arr = ProcessLine(l, "blahblah", gotMatch)

    If gotMatch Then
        For Each v In arr
            Debug.Print v
        Next v
    End If

End Sub
```

Function to process each line:

```
Function ProcessLine(line As String, keyword As String, ByRef gotMatch As Boolean)

    Dim rv As String, arr, v

    gotMatch = InStr(line, keyword) > 0

    If gotMatch Then

        rv = Split(line, keyword)(1) 'part after the keyword
        'clean up...
        rv = Replace(rv, vbTab, " ")
        rv = Replace(rv, "/", "")
        Do While InStr(rv, "  ") > 0
            rv = Replace(rv, "  ", " ")
        Loop

        arr = Split(Trim(rv), " ")

     End If 'has keyword

     ProcessLine = arr 'return array

End Function
```

**EDIT** - fixed your code

```
rw = 1
myFile = "C:\vba\text.txt" 

Open myFile For Input As #1 

Do Until EOF(1) 

    Line Input #1, l 
    arr = ProcessLine(l, "[keyword1]", gotMatch) 

    If gotMatch Then 
        Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr)+1).Value = arr 
        rw = rw + 1
    End If

Loop 

Close #1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, it works fine ! I just have to sent the results into Excel worksheet cells now and it will be fully done !

Comment: I'd like to post back my code here but formating doesn't work :/ No line feed in this textbox ?

Comment: You can add it to your question: use the `{}` button to format the code.

Comment: `myFile = "C:\vba\text.txt"
Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, l

    arr = ProcessLine(l, "[keyword1]", gotMatch)
    If gotMatch Then
    column = "A"
        For Each v In arr
            Range(column & "1").Value = v
            next_col = Asc(column) + 1
            column = Chr(next_col)
        Next v
    End If
    
Loop
Close #1`

Comment: I feel sorry but I don't see "{}" button on my browser :/

Comment: I understand now. Code button seems to be available only in answer textbox (not "comment textbox"!)

Answer (score 0):

While i recommend to split it up while importing the date, you can do it with this sub afterwards. I assume there are always 4 values and 5 cells to the right are empty (to put the values in)... the original cell text will remain (to check for errors)

```
Sub splitit()
  Dim startCell As Range
  Set startCell = Range("A1")
  Dim cellValue As Variant
  While startCell <> ""
    cellValue = startCell.Value
    cellValue = Trim(Replace(Replace(cellValue, "/", ""), vbTab, ""))
    While InStr(cellValue, "  ")
      cellValue = Replace(cellValue, "  ", " ")
    Wend
    cellValue = Split(cellValue, " ")
    startCell.Offset(0, 1) = cellValue(UBound(cellValue) - 4)
    startCell.Offset(0, 2) = cellValue(UBound(cellValue) - 3)
    startCell.Offset(0, 3) = cellValue(UBound(cellValue) - 2)
    startCell.Offset(0, 4) = cellValue(UBound(cellValue) - 1)
    startCell.Offset(0, 5) = cellValue(UBound(cellValue))
    'activate the next 2 lines to change the original cell to the first part without the extracted text
    'ReDim Preserve cellValue(LBound(cellValue) To UBound(cellValue) - 5)
    'startCell.Value = Join(cellValue, " ")
    Set startCell = startCell.Offset(1, 0)
  Wend
End Sub
```

Try to improve and merge it with your importing to do it automatically in the future...

Comment: Thank you Dirk for your help.

Comment: @Julien if you got what you where looking for or at least this code helped in some way, i'm glad i could help  
however, if you have questions, or need improvement/change, just tell it :)

Answer (score -2):

This might get you going. Had to do something similar once.

Steps:

1. Open an excel sheet.
2. Press ALT-F11.
3. Choose "Add" from the menu.
4. Choose "Module" from the dropdown.
5. Copy the source below into the newly created module.
6. Change the values behind the Public Const declarations as to suit your needs
7. Run CallImport

Short explanation of module:

FindRow - Searches for the keywords in your table and returns the cell object the keyword is found in.

IsAnArry - Tests whether a parameter is of type Array.

CallImport - The main subroutine that starts the import.

ImportEngineeringTextFile - Handles the actual import and data manipulation.

The only thing you need to change are the values behind each of the Public Const declarations to suit your need and than run CallImport. In the code below I added some comment to help understand what is going on there.

```
Public Const MY_IMPORT_TABLE_COLUMNS As String = "A:F"
Public Const FULL_PATH_TO_IMPORT_FILE_NAME As String = "Map1.txt"
Public Const COLUMS_WHERE_TO_DELETE_SLASH As String = "D:D"
Public Const COLUMNS_TO_DELETE_WHEN_DONE As String = "A:B"
Public Const DESTINATION_CELL_FOR_DATA As String = "A1"
Public Const FIRST_COLUMN_OF_MY_TABLE As String = "A:A"
Public Const KEYWORDS_1 As Variant = "[keyword1]"
Public Const KEYWORDS_2 As Variant = "[keyword3]"
'You can add more keyword declarations if need be.
'If you do so, don't forget to change the call to ImportEngineeringTextFile
'in CallImport

Function FindRow(What As Variant) As Object
    With ActiveSheet.Range(MY_IMPORT_TABLE_COLUMNS)
        Set FindRow = .Find(What, After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With
End Function

Function IsAnArray(VAR As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    I = VAR.Rows.Count
    IsAnArray = ((VarType(VAR) > vbArray Or InStr(TypeName(VAR), "()") < 1) And Err.Number <> 0)
End Function

Sub CallImport()
    Call ImportEngineeringTextFile(Array(KEYWORDS_1, KEYWORDS_2)) ' Add other keyword constants to the array if need be.
End Sub

Sub ImportEngineeringTextFile(ByVal KeyWords As Variant)
    Dim KWord As Variant, Obj As Object, ValidRows() As Variant, I As Long, R As Variant
    If Not IsAnArray(KeyWords) Then Exit Sub ' If the import parameter is not of type Array, do not continue.
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FULL_PATH_TO_IMPORT_FILE_NAME, Destination:=Range(DESTINATION_CELL_FOR_DATA))
        .Name = "Map1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells  ' This makes sure you can import over and over again with the same paramters, without cleaning the sheet first
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True ' Automatically adjust width of column after import
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False ' Do not ask for a filename
        .TextFilePlatform = 850 ' Data in file is of code page IMB850 (ANSI)
        .TextFileStartRow = 1 ' Import as from row 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited ' This indacates a delimited fields file in stead of fixed field length file
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote ' This indactes that data starting with double quote is considered to be text
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True ' Fields can be seperated by tab character
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False ' Fields can not be separated by semi-colon
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False ' Fields can not be separated by comma
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True ' Fields can be separated by a space
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) ' Data types of imported fields, need no changing since they are all set to automatic detection
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True ' Negative values can have trailing a negation sign
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Columns(COLUMS_WHERE_TO_DELETE_SLASH).Select
    Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range(DESTINATION_CELL_FOR_DATA).Select
    I = 0
    ReDim ValidRows(I)
    Set ValidRows(0) = Nothing
    For Each KWord In KeyWords ' Search for and store the rows where the keywords are found
        Set Obj = FindRow(KWord)
        If Not Obj Is Nothing Then ' A row was found containing a keyword
            ReDim Preserve ValidRows(I) ' Allocate more space for the resulting array
            Set ValidRows(I) = Obj
            I = I + 1
        End If
    Next
    For Each Obj In Range(FIRST_COLUMN_OF_MY_TABLE) ' Walk through the data table and delete all rows that do not contain one of the specified keywords
        If Obj.Value = "" Then Exit For
        I = 0
        For Each R In ValidRows 
            If Obj.Row = R.Row Then
                I = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If I = 0 Then Obj.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp ' Delete a row
    Next
    Columns(COLUMNS_TO_DELETE_WHEN_DONE).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlLeft ' Delete those columns you do not want to keep in the data table
End Sub
```

Comment: A bit difficult for me to understand (really beginner), but I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know you were a beginner, sorry. I've added some comments in the source and provide some explanation. Just copy it into a vba module in your workbook and follow the instructions. Hope this suffices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works great. I may need to adapt but the main job is done !